# Fast way to check if partial value is present in large array of hashes

Tags: ruby

I have a large array (A) containing about 50,000 values (Hashes). I have 2 other arrays containing a blacklist (B) and a whitelist (W) of values (also strings) to be checked against A. I know about the Array.include? function but I have to check if a value from B or W is partially in the key "text" of each Hash in A.

So for example:

```
A = [ { :text => 'Cat', :some_other_key => 'bla' }, 
      { :text => 'Dog', :some_other_key => 'blub' }, 
      { :text => 'Wolve', :some_other_key => 'example' }, 
      { :text => 'Bird', :some_other_key => 'test' }, 
      { :text => 'White Whale', :some_other_key => 'test' } ]
W = [ 'Whale', 'Cow' ]
B = [ 'Pig', 'Chicken' ]
```

I want to match 'White Whale' against 'Whale' from W. As far as i know, include? will only match if the values are exactly the same.

What I did so far is:

```
A.each do |value|

    if W.any? { |w| value[:text] =~ /#{w}/ }
        #Do stuff
        next
    elsif B.any? { |w| value[:text] =~ /#{w}/ }
        #Do other stuff
        next
    end
end
```

This works for me, but it's really slow if A, B or W are getting big. This finally leads me to my question: Does anyone know a better and faster way of achieving this?

Comment: Is this process being repeated with the same (or very similar) data? If so, some kind of indexing and/or caching may be appropriate. It would then be the kind of query suited to search engines and database systems (which pay the cost of indexing as you add data)

Comment: A and W are never the same, but B is shared between the different comparison operations. Would you suggest building two SQL queries and run two update operations? I tried this but I had to use ILIKE and this was even slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building the regexes is a cost that you can move out of the inner loop:

```
w_rx = W.map { |w| /#{w}/ } 
b_rx = B.map { |w| /#{w}/ }

A.each do |value|
    if w_rx.any? { |rx| value[:text] =~ rx }
        #Do stuff
        next
    elsif b_rx.any? { |rx| value[:text] =~ rx }
        #Do other stuff
        next
    end 
end
```

*Also please look at steenslag's answer*, replacing `w_rx = W.map { |w| /#{w}/ }` with `big_w_rx = Regepx.union(W)` and `w_rx.any? { |rx| value[:text] =~ rx }` with `value[:text] =~ big_w_rx` can be a lot faster. I tested it as 5 times faster, but will depend a bit on your data.

The only other way to improve on your loop would be to find a way to skip entries in A, W or B. That is in essence what indexing does, but you have a problem here that each entry in A is new to you, so the cost of indexing by any scheme is likely higher than the cost of scanning the whole list.

If you have some good knowledge about structure in each `[:text]` you could use it to your advantage. For instance if lengths of `[:text]` can routinely be less than items in `W` and `B`, then there is no need to check for matches against the longer strings. Sort `W` and `B` by length, create a hash of where the points are in the sorted lists for each length, and only test the minimum slice of W and B in the inner loops - that's obviously very specific to how the data behaves, so I'm not going to write it out in full, it may not help you.

---

A benchmark, `Regexp.union` vs `arr_of_regex.any?`

```
require 'benchmark'

W = [ 'Whale', 'Cow', 'Flat', 'Bundle', 'Bubbles', 
      'Clarinet', 'Cash', 'Fish', 'Donkey' ]

# Dummy data (lots of misses to W, so might not be representative)
a = Array.new( 100000 ) { |i| 
  (1..(5+rand(20))).map { |j| 
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".chars.sample 
  }.join 
}

big_rx = Regexp.union(W)

w_rx = W.map { |w| /#{w}/ }

Benchmark.bm do |bm|
  bm.report(:big_rx) { a.select { |s| s =~ big_rx } }
  bm.report(:w_rx) { a.select { |s| w_rx.any? { |rx| s =~ rx } } }
end
```

Output:

```
       user     system      total        real
big_rx  0.110000   0.000000   0.110000 (  0.112621)
w_rx  0.650000   0.000000   0.650000 (  0.660112)
```

If I modify W to be 1000 records, built similarly to `a` in the above example, then the difference closes to more like a factor of 2 (still, well worth having):

```
       user     system      total        real
big_rx 21.380000   0.010000  21.390000 ( 21.398051)
w_rx 39.720000   0.030000  39.750000 ( 39.759734)
```

Comment: Thank you Neil! This is a neat little trick I didn't thought of. This improved performance by round about 20%!

In Addition to your edit: Unfortunately I don't know much about the values to expect (except for B). But moving the regex out of the loop is fine for me!

Comment: Thanks for the benchmark. I succesfully implemented this and am happy now. Ruby is awesome!

Answer (score 2):

You could build huge regexps with [union](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-c-union)

```
B_res = Regexp.union(B)
W_res = Regexp.union(W)
```

(or in chunks of a few hundred of B and W), and match these against A.

Comment: Thank you very much @steenslag! I am not quite sure which answer to accept since both of you helped me a lot. I think I'll stick to @Neil Slater's answer since it's a little more detailed. Is this OK or considered bad SO behaviour?